# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate [Type]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am having issue in my current app to register a DbContext from type parameter; I'm trying to build a customizable lib.
I have a simple object named Blog

```
  public class Blog
{
    public Blog() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have custom DbContext object like so

```
public class EFStoreProjectDbContext : EFStoreProjectDbContext<Blog>
{
    public EFStoreProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) { }
    protected EFStoreProjectDbContext() { }
}

public abstract class EFStoreProjectDbContext<TBlog> : DbContext
    where TBlog : Blog
{
    public EFStoreProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) { }

    protected EFStoreProjectDbContext() { }

    public virtual DbSet<TBlog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have store that handle all queries or persistence:

```
    public class EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog> : EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog, DbContext>
    where TBlog : Blog
{
    public EFStoreProjectStore(DbContext context) : base(context) { }
}

public class EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog, TContext>
    where TBlog : Blog
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public EFStoreProjectStore(TContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context is null");
        Context = context;
    }

    public virtual TContext Context { get; private set; }
    private DbSet<TBlog> Blogs { get { return Context.Set<TBlog>(); } }

    public virtual async Task<TBlog?> CreateAsync(TBlog blog)
    {
        if (blog == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(blog));
        Blogs.Add(blog);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return blog;
    }
}
```

My Issue is here, when I'm trying to register the EFStoreProjectStore class I face the exception like so:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'EFStoreProject.EntityFramework.EFStoreProjectStore`1[EFStoreProject.EntityFramework.Store.Blog]'.

The registration object like so:

```
    public static class EFStoreProjectEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IEFStoreProjectBuilder AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>(this IEFStoreProjectBuilder builder)
      where TContext : DbContext
    {
        builder.Services.TryAddScoped(typeof(IEFStoreProjectStore<>), typeof(EFStoreProjectStore<>));
        
        return builder;
    }
}
```

The signatureof the **IEFStoreProjectStore** interface like so

```
    public interface IEFStoreProjectStore<TBlog>
where TBlog : class
{
    Task<TBlog> CreateAsync(TBlog blog);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate
> 'EFStoreProject.EntityFramework.EFStoreProjectStore`1[EFStoreProject.EntityFramework.Store.Blog]'.

has indicated :

When it trying to construct an instance of `EFStoreProjectStore<Blog>` through the constructor

```
public EFStoreProjectStore(DbContext context) : base(context) { }
```

It couldn't find the parameter type of `DbContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext)` in the service container(you haven't regist it at all)

To fix this error ,you could try :

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog() { }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
//remove abstruct

public  class EFStoreProjectDbContext<TBlog> : DbContext
    where TBlog : Blog
{
    public EFStoreProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions) { }

    protected EFStoreProjectDbContext() { }

    public virtual DbSet<TBlog> Blog { get; set; } = default!;
}


public interface IEFStoreProjectStore<TBlog>
where TBlog : class
    {
        Task<TBlog> CreateAsync(TBlog blog);
    }
    public class EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog, TContext> : IEFStoreProjectStore<TBlog>
    where TBlog : Blog
    where TContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFStoreProjectStore(TContext context)
        {
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context is null");
            Context = context;
        }

    public virtual TContext Context { get; private set; }
    private DbSet<TBlog> Blog { get { return Context.Set<TBlog>(); } }

    public virtual async Task<TBlog?> CreateAsync(TBlog blog)
    {
        if (blog == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(blog));
        Blog.Add(blog);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return blog;
    }
}
public class EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog> : EFStoreProjectStore<TBlog, EFStoreProjectDbContext<TBlog>>
where TBlog : Blog
{
    public EFStoreProjectStore(EFStoreProjectDbContext<TBlog> context) : base(context) { }
}

// it should be WebApplicationBuilder by default
public static class EFStoreProjectEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions
{
    public static WebApplicationBuilder AddEntityFrameworkStores(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
 
    {
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<EFStoreProjectDbContext<Blog>>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer("connectstring"));
        builder.Services.TryAddScoped(typeof(IEFStoreProjectStore<>), typeof(EFStoreProjectStore<>));
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Regist Services in program.cs:

```
builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores();
```

inject  into controller :

```
private readonly IEFStoreProjectStore<Blog> _store;
.......
```

it works on myside when I debug:

[image]

Comment: I try your code but it's not working and show the same error

Comment: I've updated all codes related ,it works on my side now,hopes help

Comment: Yeah, now it's working I forget to implement the IEFStoreProjectStore interface inside the EFStoreProjectStore object.